# Which German podcasts on Spotify have regular new content and lots of talking?

Tags: learning

Which Spotify podcasts are speaking-heavy (in German) with lots of new content of general interest?

Deutschlandfunk is pretty good and looking for similar, something with even more talking constantly.

Thank you

Comment: He, I wonder how you can want 'more talking' than Deutschlandfunk. It's a live broadcast radio station with lots of formats where they go into depths on certain topics. As podcast simply choose the broadcasts from them which have no music content. There's also NDR info for example, thus the news channels of other radio stations

Comment: What else do people do on podcasts except talk? I am confused. Also why is it important that the podcast is on Spotify?

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a list of podcast ressources, but did not find any. There's a lot of good podcast websites - with all kind of topics. I won't focus on Spotify in particular - because that's just at the end of a search within Spotify, but one can get a list of trending podcasts by searching for things like "spotify podcast deutsch". But let's make this a community wiki on possibly good podcasts:

- https://spotify_presse.prowly.com/118349-spotify-jahresruckblick-die-top-podcasts-2020
- https://deutschepodcasts.de/
- https://podwatch.io/charts/allgemeinbildungs-podcasts/

But on the other hand, it is very limited to only use that platform as there are so many places in the internet for good podcast. Especially the public radio networks have extensive 'mediatheken' where you can find most broadcasts online as podcast:

- https://www.ardaudiothek.de/sender/ard/ - The public broadcasting
  (ARD). Many of its radio programmes are found here.
- https://www.deutschlandfunk.de/ - The public nationwide radio
  station. Everything available as podcast, too.